# ambiguous error in vc++ with ImageMagicK

Tags: c++, imagemagick

I have got a question.
When I compiled with ImageMagicK library in vs2010 c++ form project.

I've got some error codes like this.

1>ex3.cpp(22): error C2872: 'Image' : ambiguous symbol

1>          could be 'c:\program files\imagemagick-6.8.6-q16\include\Magick++/Image.h(55) : Magick::Image'

1>          or       'c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework.netframework\v4.0\system.drawing.dll : System::Drawing::Image'

The file looks like this:

```
// ex3.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Form1.h"
#include <Magick++.h>


using namespace ex3;
using namespace Magick; 

[STAThreadAttribute]
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    // Enabling Windows XP visual effects before any controls are created
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 
    // Create the main window and run it
    Application::Run(gcnew Form1());


    InitializeMagick(*argv);
    Image master;
    master.read("C:₩₩abc.jpg");
    master.addNoise(ImpulseNoise);
    master.write("C:₩₩abc_magic.jpg");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The link doesn't work. Why don't post the code here instead. 22 lines cannot be too much.

Comment: @Bo Persson : sorry for that. I have update the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of when `using namespace xxx` is causing a conflict. On the line

```
Image master;
```

the compiler cannot tell if you mean `Magick::Image` or the .NET `Image`.

You can select the one you probably need by being explicit and write

```
Magick::Image master;
```

This is exactly the reason for inventing namespaces in the first place, and why it is strongly recommended **not** to add `using namespace xxx` to the files, just to save some typing.

Like Victor Torres says in his answer, it is uncertain if ImageMagick at all works with Managed C++, but that is another problem.

Comment: Sir I have solve that problem with your answer. Thanks. BTW.  I have one error at this InitializeMagick(*argv);  the error message what 'argv' undeclared identifier. In this case, what am I supposed to do for solving?

Comment: I'm not a sir, but the `argv` might be one problem with using Managed C++. In native C++ the main function looks like `int main(int argc, char* argv[]);`, and there is the `argv` to pass to initialization. How to do that with an `^args`, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

After doing research on web sight.
vc++ does not seem to be a choice from imagemagick software suite. Didnt see vc++ as interface